# find the longest GrowingSequence in a List JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I try to solve an exercise about collection about find the longest sequence of a List Integer
Check my code

```
public void findLongestSequence(List<Integer> values)
   {
       List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
       List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
           temp.add(values.get(i-1));
           if(values.get(i)<values.get(i-1))
           {
               if(temp.size()>= result.size())
               {
                   result.clear();
                   result.addAll(temp);
                   temp.clear();
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println(values);
       System.out.println(result);
   }
```

The problem is my code is never check the value of the last element.

Input : List list = List.of(7, 2, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

Result : [1, 2, 3, 8]

Expected : [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Hint: it is failing when the longest sequence is at the very end of the input

Comment: Have a closer look at your loop condition, in combination with this line:  `temp.add(values.get(i-1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because of you skip the last value having the `temp.add(values.get(i-1));`

I've fixed it for you:

```
public static void findLongestSequence(List<Integer> values) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        temp.add(values.get(i));
        if ((values.size() == i + 1) || values.get(i) > values.get(i + 1)) {
            if (temp.size() >= result.size()) {
                result.clear();
                result.addAll(temp);
            }
            temp.clear();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(values);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```